# Is $\frac{y!}{y+1}$ an integer if $y$ is an odd number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I was playing around with equations and I somehow stumbled upon the idea that if $y$ is an odd number then $\dfrac{y!}{y+1}$ is an integer. I have tried many numbers, but I do not know if I can prove it or if it is even true.

Can someone provide a proof if this is true, or a counter-example if this is false?

Comment: Let $y=3$, then $\frac{3!}{3+1} = \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: $(y! /y) +1 = (y-1)! +1 $ always an integer even if $y $is not odd. And if the question is $(y!) /(y+1) $ then the conclusion that it is a whole number is false.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote.

Comment: It is also true for even $y$, as long as $y+1$ isn't prime.

Answer (score 3):

If $y$ is odd, then we can rewrite $y$ as $2x+1$, for some integer $x$. Then,

$$\frac{(2x+1)!}{2x+2} = \frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot...\cdot x\cdot (x+1)\cdot (x+2) \cdot ...\cdot (2x+1)}{2\cdot(x+1)}$$

As you can see, you can cancel the $2$ and the $(x+1)$, leaving behind a product of integers which will, hence, be an integer.

However, for this to be true, $(x+1)>2 \Rightarrow x>1 \Rightarrow y>3$. And we get counterexamples for $y=1$ and $y=3$, as others have pointed. Hope this helps.

Edit: To clarify why the condition is required, if it does not hold, then $2$ and $(x+1)$ will not be distinct terms in the numerator but will be so in the denominator, making this line of reasoning not true.

In summary, I showed that the statement is mostly true, except for two very small counterexamples.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

If $y>4$, when $y=2n$ you have that $(y-1)!/y=(2n-1)!/2n$.
But $2n$ divides $(2n-1)!$, since both $2$ and $n$ are distinct factors of $(2n-1)!$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).